# How can I dynamically assign css line-height to nested objects using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, inheritance, nested, css

I'm developing a horizontal family tree.

**Current Step** - Assigning CSS Line-Height to vertically center each item based on nested content.

**Problem** - The nested item's Line-Height value grows exponentially because of inheritance.
I can make it work by assigning each value individually, but I'm looking for a dynamic solution.

> View my demo code here - http://jsfiddle.net/kirtcarter/TLJT9/

Here's the jQuery in question:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#familytree li").each(function(n) {
        var LineHeight = $(this).height()+'px';
        $(this).css({'line-height':LineHeight});
    });
});
```

**Desired Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing something along these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").each(function(n) {
        var newLineHeight = $(this).parent('.wrapper').height() +'px';
        $(this).css({'line-height':newLineHeight});
    });
});​
```

Comment: Reversing the order works (like **jfrej** suggested)...but I think this solution is more scalable. Especially when this thing gets connected to a DB and really blows up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to traverse the objects in a different order - starting from children.

Also, you might want to reset `line-height` to 1 before you check the height.

Try this:

```
$($("#familytree li").get().reverse()).each(function(n) {
    var newLineHeight = $(this).height()+'px';
    //uncomment the following line and run to see issue
    $(this).css({'line-height':newLineHeight});
});
```

Or in a more readable way:

```
var $elements = $("#familytree li");
var $elementsReversed = $($elements.get().reverse());
$elementsReversed.each(function(n) {
    var newLineHeight = $(this).height()+'px';
    //uncomment the following line and run to see issue
    $(this).css({'line-height':newLineHeight});
});
```

[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/TLJT9/10/)

Comment: I had considered reversing the order in which they were assigned but wasn't sure how to do it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

css

```
#familytree li{   line-height: 100%; }
```

Looks like every one of these has an explicit height, so this should work